# ggplot2, introduce breaks on a x log scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot like this:

```
 p<-ggplot() +
 geom_line(data= myData, aes(x = myData$x , y = myData$y)) +
 scale_x_log10()+
 scale_y_log10()
```

My x value is `seq(9880000, 12220000, 10000)`

There is only one break on the x-axis of the plot, what should I do if to get at least 3 breaks on the plot x-axis?

Comment: Please consider adding some example data to make your question "reproducible", meaning that we should be able to run your posted code in a fresh R session and reproduce the problem you need solved.

Comment: In general, it is bad practice to use `$` indexing inside of `aes()` even though it sometimes seems to work just fine. Instead, try `aes(x=x, y=y)` (assuming your data.frame `myData` has columns named `x` and `y`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is fully reproducible example of the original poster's problem where a log-scaled plot only displays one break value on the x-axis. I demonstrate three possible solutions below.

```
library(ggplot2)

# Create a reproducible example data.frame using R functions.
x = seq(9880000, 12220000, 10000)

# Use set.seed() so that anyone who runs this code
# will get the same sequence of 'random' values.
set.seed(31415) 
y = cumsum(runif(n=length(x), min=-1e5, max=1e5)) + 1e6

dat = data.frame(x=x, y=y)

# Original poster's plot.
p1 = ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
     geom_line() +
     scale_x_log10() +
     scale_y_log10() +
     labs(title="1. Plot has only one x-axis break.")

# Add extra x-axis breaks manually.
x_breaks = c(10^7.0, 10^7.04, 10^7.08)
p2 = ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
     geom_line() +
     scale_x_log10(breaks=x_breaks) +
     scale_y_log10() +
     labs(title="2. Add some x-axis breaks manually.")


# Add extra x-axis breaks in semi-automated manner.
x_breaks = 10^pretty(log10(x))
x_labels = formatC(x_breaks, format = "e", digits = 2)
p3 = ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
     geom_line() +
     scale_x_log10(breaks=x_breaks, labels=x_labels) +
     scale_y_log10() +
     labs(title="3. Create x-axis breaks with R functions.")



# Skip the log10 scale because the x-values don't span multiple orders of magnitude.
p4 = ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
     geom_line() +
     scale_y_log10() +
     labs(title="4. Check appearance without log10 scale for x-axis.")


library(gridExtra)
ggsave("example.png", plot=arrangeGrob(p1, p2, p3, p4, nrow=2),
       width=10, height=5, dpi=150)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I add: `scale_x_log10(breaks=seq(9880000, 12220000, 1000000))`.

This is my reproducible example:

```
library(random)
library(ggplot2)

z <- randomStrings(n=235, len=5, digits=TRUE, upperalpha=TRUE, loweralpha=TRUE, unique=TRUE, check=TRUE)
x <- seq(9880000, 12220000, 10000)
y <- randomNumbers(n=235, min=9880000, max=12220000, col=1)

df <- data.frame(z, x, y)

head(df)
     V1       x     V1.1
1 378VO 9880000 11501626
2 AStRK 9890000 10929705
3 sotp4 9900000 11305700
4 AS4DR 9910000 11302110
5 7iFdk 9920000 11611918
6 HIS7z 9930000 11175074

p<-ggplot() + geom_line(data= df, aes(x = df$x , y = df$V1.1)) + scale_y_log10()
p + scale_x_log10(breaks=seq(9880000, 12220000, 1000000))
```

Hope it is useful...

Answer (score 0):

Add this between your parenthesis:  breaks=seq(*specify, breaks, here*)

For example, if you wanted a break at 0, 10, 100:
scale_x_log10((breaks=seq(0,10,100))

Comment: I guess you probably meant `breaks=c(0, 10, 100)` rather than `seq()`?