# How can I enforce ggplot2 to put more than one tick on an axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the example below, you can see that ggplot2 only puts one tick on the x axis, because scale_log10_x() only puts ticks on orders of magnitude. An axis with one tick is useless haha. What I'd like to do is have it stick to orders of magnitude for each facet if the data range is appropriate, but add a tick at some other (automatically chosen) number if the data has too constricted a range. How can I do this?

```
require(ggplot2)

example <- data.frame(x=c(.7,.5,.57,.59,.9,1.2,.7,.5,.3,.3,.1,1.2), y=rnorm(n=12), group=rep(c('a','b'), each=6))

ggplot(data=example, mapping=aes(x=x, y=y))+
  scale_x_log10()+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~group, scales='free')
```

[image]

Comment: Use the "breaks" option in `scale_x_log10()`

Comment: Joran: that's very strange... maybe it's a problem w. my ggplot2 version number, or some options I set. Hrm I'll investigate further.

Comment: Dave2e ... I don't want fixed breaks. I want breaks that are adaptive to the data.

Comment: Have a look at another similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55113333/ggplot2-introduce-breaks-on-a-x-log-scale/55114962